# Return value of cell in row below today's date

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Newer to Google sheets and am loving it. Using it to organize my entire teaching life! Quick question. I have a top row with all the dates from this school year. The rows below each represent a home room teacher and the lessons I will be teaching to their class. I would like to send a query that retrieves whatever lesson is being taught "today" and brings it over next to the teachers name. I've somehow hacked my way into achieving far more complicated equations and know this should be simple, Just can't get anything to work. Suggestions?

Tried a v lookup formula with only errors. tried a query formula, no bueno! a little embarrassed to post my hacked formulas here but here is a link to a copy of my sheet. Look at tab "Master Lesson Schedule 2022-23" trying to pull the lessons under todays date into the column under "today's lesson". This is ultimately so I can pull this data onto the class schedule sheet then onto the today sheet, but that is a different problem I will tackle later. Please take a look if you have time. Thank you to all the amazing geniuses on this forum!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KebgHgoGBrciJBbjGiTVn-3pHTm2kGr29ib1kxAL7ik/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in `Cell A4` of `Master Lesson Schedule 2022-23`

```
=filter(FK4:LC,FK2:LC2=today())
```

Comment: Your amazing! Thank you. Mind is kind of blown right now.